# How can I tell which pages of a site are indexed by Google or Bing?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, bing

Is there a tool that can list the specific pages of a site which are indexed by the search engines?

I know the webmaster tools have this stuff, but it just tells how many pages out of the sitemap, which isn't that useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Google you can use the "site:" operator. Example: [site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=google+site%3A#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=site%3astackoverflow.com&pbx=1&oq=site%3astackoverflow.com)

I couldn't find an equivlant for Bing.

[This page](http://tech4idiots.org/2011/05/03/google-search-operators/) summarizes the operators that each of the major search engines offer.

Comment: So if I use site:domain.com - the results are all pages? Or only the indexed pages? The reason I ask is that I am trying to de-index some pages and want to see if they are there still. - Thanks!

Comment: It should be all pages. If you are trying to de-Index pages best bet is wmt ensure you also block via robots.txt wait a few days then try an exact match search.

Comment: Bing also supports site:example.com to list all indexed pages within a site. Entering the same into yahoo will take you to the site explorer website where you can delete url's directly. Note that the site:example.com search may omit some pages where two or more pages contain similar content.

Answer (score 0):

[Bing Webmaster Tools](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster/) has a feature called "Index Explorer" which does exactly what you ask and lists every page they have indexed.

There is no equivalent in Google as far as I know. Using the `site:` operator is a poor substitute because it is very unreliable and inaccurate. You could try the "Internal links" section in Google Webmaster Tools, as it should list every page linked to that Google has indexed.